# Git comparing 2 branches and identify what got committed

Tags: git, gitlab

I have requirement to find what is ready in develop branch that can be moved to master branch for deployment. I am not interested in specific files or multiple commits happening in that branch. I want a summary. Let's say there are 3 developers and each one of them created a feature branch for their changes. Now they keep on committing work in their branches and ultimately submit the work for review. I want that final commit reported in my report. I used below command and it worked to some extent but it failed to get a commit probably that was of type 'Merge and Squash'

```
git log origin/master..origin/develop --first-parent --merges --pretty=format:"%<(20,trunc)%an %C(white)%<(15)%ar%Creset %s %b"
```

For e.g.

```
Fix for Fetch order log calling multiple times
@xyz
xyz committed last month

Merge pull request #588 from repo/ma-delivery-trackerfix 
@xyz
xyz committed last month
```

out of these I only want

```
Merge pull request #588 from repo/ma-delivery-trackerfix
```

One dev had only 1 reviewer and when that reviewer approved the PR the changes got merged without this Merge message. It was like below

```
add logic to display gift card image on orderview page (#587)
@xyz1
xyz1 committed last month
```

above is the only statement I see and so my command missed it. How may I fix this?